# Compactness in Hilbert space $\ell^2$

Tags: metric-spaces

If we have a **compact** set $A$ contained in $\ell^2$ (Hilbert Space),
how can we show that $A$ is **closed and bounded**?

Comment: In $l^2$ closed and bounded is not equivalent with compact.

Comment: The implication does hold @Math_QED.

Answer (score 2):

This holds in any metric space, closedness because of Hausdorffness and boundedness by considering covers like $\{B(x,n): m \in \mathbb{N}\}$ for a fixed $x$.

Closed and bounded does not imply compactness, the unit ball is a counterexample (what limit can a subsequence of $(e_n)$ have?).